# Is it always true that $Aut_F(H_0) \cong Aut_F(H_1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, computability, automorphism-group

Suppose $G$ is a group. Let's call a total recursive function $F: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ a *functional representation* if, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $n \mapsto F(i, n)$ is a bijection and $\langle \{ n \mapsto F(i, n) \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \rangle \cong G$. Let's call $G$ *functionally constructive* iff it accepts a functional representation and let's call $\langle \{ n \mapsto F(i, n) \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \rangle < \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ its *functional embedding*.

Now, suppose $G$ is a functionally constructive group and $H < \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ is its functional embedding. Let's define a *functional representation of an automorphism* $\alpha \in \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ as a pair of functional representations of $G$, $F_0$ and $F_1$, such that:

1. $\langle \{ n \mapsto F_0(i, n) \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \rangle = \langle \{ n \mapsto F_1(i, n) \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \rangle = H$;
2. $(\forall i \in \mathbb{N}) \quad \alpha((n \mapsto F_0(i, n))) =  (n \mapsto F_1(i, n))$.

Let's call an automorphism of $H$ that has a functional representation *functionally constructive*. Let's call the set of all functionally constructive automorphisms of $H$ as $\operatorname{Aut}_F(H)$. It is not hard to see, that it is a group.

My question is:

> Suppose $G$ is a functionally constructive group and $H_0$ and $H_1$ are its functional embeddings. Is it always true that $\operatorname{Aut}_F(H_0) \cong \operatorname{Aut}_F(H_1)$?

For finite $G$ it is obviously true, because all automorphisms of finite groups are functionally constructive for any their functional embedding. However, I have no idea, what happens when $G$ is infinite...

Comment: Is $\langle \{n\mapsto F(i,n)\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\rangle$ the closure under inversion and composition of the set of functions of the form $n\mapsto F(i,n)$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$, viewed as a group w/r/t composition?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes.